# How can I get a list of asset pathnames in Rails 6? (Sprockets::Assets no longer has a to_a method)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-6

I have the following code in an application running in Rails 5:

```rb
  def application_spec_files
    Rails.application.assets.find_asset('application_spec.js').to_a.map {|e| e.pathname.to_s }
  end
```

That generates an array of pathnames for asset files. It looks like this:

```rb
["/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/jquery-rails-4.3.3/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.js",
 "/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/jquery-rails-4.3.3/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js",
 "/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js",
 # etc. 
]
```

However, when attempting to run this code in Rails 6, it no longer works. I get this error:

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_a' for #<Sprockets::Asset...`

Is there a way I can generate a list of pathnames in Rails 6?

Comment: `Rails.application.assets.paths`

Comment: @dbugger, that provides a list of all directories, not all javascript files referenced in the application_spec file.